# Unable to generate WSDL 1.1 for this service

Tags: apache-axis

I have a wsdl (that works) and I've generated boilerplate code from it but wish to use my original wsdl not the auto generated one but on changing useOriginalwsdl to true I get errors. There is absolutely no documentation in the Axis website regarding this property so I have followed the steps here:
[useOriginalwsdl=true is not working in axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242394/useoriginalwsdl-true-is-not-working-in-axis2)

specifically:

1. My services.xml has the same name as the wsdl service name
2. I have called my wsdl service.wsdl and put it in the META-INF folder (I also tried it with the service name)

But I get the error Unable to generate WSDL 1.1 for this service

Below is my folder structure:

```
.\com
.\lib
.\META-INF
   services.xml
   service.wsdl
```

My services.xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- This file was auto-generated from WSDL -->
<!-- by the Apache Axis2 version: 1.6.2  Built on : Apr 17, 2012 (05:33:49 IST) -->
<serviceGroup>
    <service name="MyService">
        <messageReceivers>
            <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out" class="com.neil.systems.ServiceMessageReceiverInOut"/>
        </messageReceivers>
        <parameter name="ServiceClass">com.neil.webservice.MyService</parameter>
        <parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="modifyUserWSDLPortAddress">false</parameter>
        <operation name="Provision" mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out" namespace="http://xmlns.neil.com/systems">
            <actionMapping>http://xmlns.neil.com/systems/Provision</actionMapping>
            <outputActionMapping>http://xmlns.neil.com/systems/ProvisionResponse</outputActionMapping>
        </operation>
    </service>
</serviceGroup>
```

My service.wsdl, the relevant part is:

```
<wsdl:service name="MyService">
```

Note, I changed a couple of things in the services.xml to reduce the size so any obvious errors is just down to my cutting.

Comment: Do you have any references in your namespace to xsd files? Those xsd files have to be put in the META-INF folder as well. In addition, you may try to define your wsdl file starting with `<wsdl:definitions name="ObjectReplicationServiceLayer_V1_0" ...` instead of `<wsdl:service name...`