# Error retrieving wsdl through URL from service

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, wildfly-17

In my application I use as a web server Widlfly 17.0.1 and for the wsdl webservices Axis2 1.7.6

I get an error when trying to retrieve the wsdl through URL by a client program from the server URL like http://myserver:8080/myapp/services/MyService?wsdl

When I hit the URL in the browser I get

```
<error>
  <description>Unable to generate WSDL 1.1 for this service</description>
  <reason>
    If you wish Axis2 to automatically generate the WSDL 1.1, then please set useOriginalwsdl as false in 
    your services.xml
  </reason>
</error>
```

So far I have tried the suggested solution from here [useOriginalwsdl=true is not working in axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242394/useoriginalwsdl-true-is-not-working-in-axis2)
but without success, the error still remains the same.

Also my wsdl and xsd seem to be valid and the servers service endpoint is also working fine and as expected.

When I use soapUI or my client with provided wsdl, the service seems working fine and is returning the desired response.

But I need to retrieve the wsdl to the client through the servers service URL like http://myserver:8080/myapp/services/MyService?wsdl because for technical restrictions I cannot provide it in the client project.

My services.xml is following:

```
   <service name="MyService">
        <messageReceivers>
            <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out" class="org.test.MyServiceMessageReceiverInOut"/>
        </messageReceivers>
        <parameter name="ServiceClass">org.test.MyServiceSkeleton</parameter>
        <parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="modifyUserWSDLPortAddress">true</parameter>
        <operation name="getDocument" mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out" namespace="http://ws.test.org/myapp/myservice">
            <actionMapping>getValue</actionMapping>
            <outputActionMapping>http://ws.test.org/myapp/myservice/myservicePortType/output2</outputActionMapping>
        </operation>
        <operation name="setValue" mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out" namespace="http://ws.test.org/myapp/myservice">
            <actionMapping>setValue</actionMapping>
            <outputActionMapping>http://ws.test.org/myapp/myservice/myservicePortType/output1</outputActionMapping>
        </operation>
    </service>
```

The service declaration inside the wsdl file is as follows:

```
   <service name="MyService">
        <port name="myservicePort" binding="tns:myserviceBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://${MyHost}:${MyPort}/myapp/services/MyService"/>
        </port>
    </service>
```

Any ideas from anybody?